# POST requests are being called twice in angular 2 after Options request

Tags: angular

I don't know but my POST requests are being called twice. May I know the fix for this? I tried using share() too but to no avail.

The following is my code

On html component,
[image]

On Component.ts
[image]

http code
[image]

[image]

First is "Options" request and after that 2 POST calls are executed

Comment: Can you upload the http code ?

Comment: are you binding any observable directly to the HTML?

Comment: We are not binding any observable directly to the HTML.

Comment: is your onSubmit method also being called multiple times?

Comment: nope, its called on button click only.. i have put html code as well

Comment: i just noticed..its calling Options method 2 times and then post method 2 times